# Traveling from the UK to America via Mexico, no bags. Will Customs challenge this?

Tags: usa, borders, texas

I'm going to America and specifically Texas. However my flight lands in Mexico and I'm crossing the border on foot. My friends are giving me a lift to the border bridge, but they are carrying on in car as they are American citizens and there is less fuss, as I am traveling as a UK citizen, I need to do the full border process and why I'm visiting things.

If I leave my bags in the car with my friends, and they take it to my apartment, and I cross with just the things I need such as passport, wallet, ESTA form, and things like that, will they challenge why I have no bags, and is it okay for my friends to take my bags for me?

Also, is there anything I should be ready for crossing the border? (First time going to Mexico or America)

Comment: Why don't you cross with your friends?

Comment: They don't want to wait around in the car for me since it will take me longer for me to go through the process, and I need to go pick my car up but where I am going I don't want to be carrying all of my bags

Comment: Well, I suppose you could do it, but it might not help your friends to be carrying someone's bags who _isn't_ in the car. They could be delayed _much longer_ than they would otherwise if it was just you had to go inside and get fingerprinted and pay $6.

Comment: Thank you Michael, just to ask, is it $6 anyway? I thought that was only to pay if you didn't already pay the $14 for ESTA? And would you know roughly how long it will take for me to be green lighted through the border, and if it is much longer than an American citizen to be allowed back in?

Comment: @Cam Regarding the extra payment, it depends on the crossing. Several will exempt ESTA holders from having to full out the form; either you don't get one at all, or a pre-filled one is printed. Also, the "ESTA form" is nothing you need to print; it's stored electronically.

Comment: The first time you've ever visited the US? Unless you set off some alarm bells, it's only really going to be an extra couple of minutes. But having CBP tear your friends' car apart because you weren't in it will take _hours_. If I were your friends, I'd keep you in the car and wait for you.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions.  Putting on hold for now.